# Where do I attach a bobber?

Tags: fishing

I am going to use live worms for fishing in a local pond, but i don't know where to put the bobber on the line.

I have a regular ball shaped bobber and a taller, skinnier one. Where/how to i put them on the line?

These are the two bobbers:

[image]
*without the string and hook*
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A bobber will hold the string a certain distance below the surface of the water. Putting the bobber onto the string 5 feet from the end will result in the hook with the bait being just 5 feet below the surface of the water.

How far you want up the string them depends on the type of fish and the body of water, but you don't want it so long that the hook has enough string to be resting on the bottom with slack as then if the fish bites, you won't see it right away.

How to attach the bobber to the string depends on the bobber, but usually there are hooks on either end that you wrap the string around and then clamp the bobber so that the string can't come off.

In your case, the top bobber is a slib bobber, and it works by running the string through the bobber with a knot tied above to keep it from going up the line too far. See [here](http://www.catchingcrappie.com/slipbobber.html) or [here](https://roundvalleyfishing.com/2014/10/04/shore-fishing-101-slip-bobbers/) for more information.

The bottom bobber is a clip on, what you will want to do is push the round button on the top down,and wrap the line around the hook that will be exposed as well as the one directly on the other side.

Comment: Thank you. So you are saying that if i want to put a worm about 10 feet down i should get 10ft of line out and then put it at the top? Also how to I set up the skinnier bobber?

Comment: @AT Yes, and see my last edit

Comment: For depths past a few feet a slip bobber makes all the difference, it is much easier to cast when all you have to adjust is a little knot on the line to set depth, with a traditional bobber to fish 10ft down you would not be able to cast very easily, not to mention when you catch something it will be 10ft from the tip of the rod when reeled in! With a slip bobber you can cast easier as you dont have all that extra slack line at the end of the rod. Slip bobbers are the only way to go if you want to do serious bobber fishing in my opinion.